# How to test a nested promise function using jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, jestjs

The simple version of code I have for now is

```
const func = (arg1,arg2) =>{
    const param1;

    return promiseA(arg1).then(data => {
         arg2.forEach(element => {
            promiseB(param1, element, data).then(output => {
                if(output === "null"){
                    throw PATH_ERROR; // This is the error I want to test, but it does not catch in test
                }
                console.log(output);
            }).catch(e=>{
                console.log(e);
                return e;
            });
        });
    });
};
```

The jest testing code I have for now is:

```
describe('func function test',  () =>{
    it('Should throw PATH_ERROR if promiseB cannot find the route', () =>{
        expect.assertions(1);
        return func(arg1,arg2).catch(e=>{
            expect(e).toMatch("PATH_ERROR");
        });

    });
});
```

Right now, the test will fail because the actual `expect.assersions()` is `0` instead of `1`. I think this is because the `.catch()` in jest is testing the `promiseA` function, since the `func` return the `promiseA`,  however the error is throw by `promiseB`.

So my question is: if it is what I thought, how can I test the inner promise function in a nested promise function.

I am still learning jest and promise, if the code structure is not quite right for testing or normal developing, please pointing out with no hesitate. Thank you so much for helping me here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--this error is always caught by your code, so it seems that the throw is an implementation detail within this function. The way to test the behavior seems to be giving it an input you know will throw, then asserting on the side effect or result/outcome of the function commensurate with that scenario.

Comment: Thanks for sharing ideas! Sorry maybe I did not give the full details, the error actually will not be caught every time. I have manually test in CLI for both "will throw error input" and "will not throw error input" and the results are meet the expectation.

Comment: I don't see how a `catch` could avoid catching the `PATH_ERROR` that the promise callback throws. It's `return`ing the error object, not rethrowing it. In other words, I don't see any execution that would throw a catchable error that's reachable for the jest code (excepting unintended errors, of course).

Answer (score 2):

You need to return promises of `promiseB()` in `promiseA()` and should change the statement `return e` in catch to `throw e`.

```
const func = (arg1,arg2) =>{
    const param1;

    return promiseA(arg1).then(data => {
        const promises = []
        arg2.forEach(element => {
            const promise = promiseB(param1, element, data).then(output => {
                if(output === "null"){
                    throw PATH_ERROR; // This is the error I want to test, but it does not catch in test
                }
                console.log(output);
            }).catch(e=>{
                console.log(e);
                throw e;
            });

            promises.push(promise)
        });

        return Promise.all(promises);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you @cuspymd ! You make my test work! Never think to use a promises list, I should really dive deeper about it. Thanks!